# How do I get a csv from Google Drive into RStudio and vice versa?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform

I have an automated R script that is running within Google Cloud. Within my R code I want to pull a csv file from my google drive, transform it in R, and then export it back into my google drive. for example

```
# Code to Pull csv from Google Drive
Trials <- fromGoogleDrive(file = "WHO.csv")
# Code to Transform and Update the csv data
...
# Code to Export dataframe to Google Drive and replace old file
exportGoogleDrive(Trials,file = "WHO.csv")
```

Obviously the functions don't actually exist but just using that as an example. Is this something I'm able to do? and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `googledrive` package in R to manipulate files in Google Drive. See: https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/ for usage examples.